# Python: PyLaTeX hyperlink to a URL

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I would like to add a text with a hyperlink to my document being generated via pyLaTeX. In LaTeX this would be performed by using:

`\href{http://www.sharelatex.com}{Something Linky}`

I have found the [labelref documentation](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.labelref.html) containing the Marker object as well as the Hyperref Object but i cannot seem to get it working.

```
from pylatex import Document, Hyperref

doc = Document()
doc.append("Example text a link should go ")
# i was hoping the hyperlink would work like i'm showing below
doc.append(Hyperref("https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX", "here"))
doc.generate_pdf("Example_document", clean_tex=True)
```

Running the following code produces the a pdf document without errors. [image of the document produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kom35.png)

While what i would expect is that the word "here" is a hyperlink and shown in blue.

Comment: What is the output you actually get? Or error messages, if any?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the document is generated however, since i am incorrectly using the Hyperref object, the hyperlink is not created.

Comment: Running your code, it outputs `\hyperref[https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX]{here}` to `Example_document.tex`. That line is trying to reference a *label*, not a URL. It also mentions in the [documentation you linked](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/pylatex/pylatex.labelref.html) that the class is meant to reference label/ref parameters. Doesn't look like this package can automatically reference URLs like how you want.

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. Thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I do it.  I created a class that gives you the needed hyperlink functionality.  There is also an issue on GitHub where I contributed this as well.  https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX/issues/264

```py
    from pylatex import Document, Hyperref, Package
    from pylatex.utils import escape_latex, NoEscape

    def hyperlink(url,text):
        text = escape_latex(text)
        return NoEscape(r'\href{' + url + '}{' + text + '}')

    doc = Document()
    doc.packages.append(Package('hyperref'))
    doc.append("Example text a link should go ")
    # i was hoping the hyperlink would work like i'm showing below
    doc.append(hyperlink("https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX", "here"))
    doc.generate_pdf("Example_document", clean_tex=True)
```

Comment: If you, like me, are looking for a way to link to a section or subsection of your document, you can adapt this like so: `def sectionLink(section, text): text = escape_latex(text) return NoEscape(r'\hyperref[' + section + ']{' + text + '}')`. The 'section' part is the label you assign via Section(), e.g. something like `'sec:toc'`.